# Persisting user-specific settings server-side in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, persistence

Originally I was using isolated storage to store user settings in a Silverlight app I inherited, when the mandate came down to persist the settings server-side so that no matter which machine a user logs in on, his settings are applied.

Is there a standard way to do this? My app does its communication to the server via a WCF service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it's standard or not, but we store the user settings in the database - treat them like any other server side data.

The best approach is to store an XML chunk which you can then parse and update on the client. Having a table with a column for each piece of information is probably a bad idea as you will want to change the data at some point.